# How do I set URLs as hyperlinks in Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I copied some text into a slide that includes URLs, like so:

- **Some text here https://myaddress.net**
- **more text http://asdf.ghjk**

However, the URLs are just plain text without hyperlinks.  Is there a faster way to set them as hyperlinks without copying the URL, going into **Hyperlink** and setting the URL there?  Maybe some kind of command that will turn all the URLs in the presentation into hyperlinks?

Comment: What version of PowerPoint are you working with? You should be able to use the keyboard shortcut "ctrl + k" to insert a hyperlink

Comment: No, other than Mike's shortcut (which will work in all Windows versions of PowerPoint) or Command/Cloverleaf/Splat+K which works on Mac versions.  It'd probably be possible to write a VBA routine to do the conversion for you; if you have some skill with VBA, you might want to give that a try; visit StackOverflow if you run into problems with it; there are sections specifically for PPT/VBA.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, I'm fine with VBA so I'll go that route if I have to, seems like it won't be that difficult to make a function that makes a link out of whatever text is currently selected, or even something that just converts all the URLs in the presentation using regex.

Comment: @sigil I'm curious ... how did the text get into PPT in the first place, and which version of PPT do you have?  I ask because here (PPT 2010) as soon as I type text that looks like a URL into PPT, PPT converts it to a hyperlink automatically.  The same thing happens when I copy/paste your URLs above into a text box. (later) I see that I can type non-url text into a text box, then edit it to become a URL and voila, no instant-hyperlink.  So maybe that's it.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, I pasted a bunch of bibliography entries that included URLs into PPT, where indeed the URLs were converted into hyperlinks.  But I needed to alphabetize the entries by author, so I wrote a script that dropped them all into Excel, alphabetized them, and then created new PPT slides and added them in as TextRanges.  Adding them back in programmatically did not convert them to hyperlinks automatically.

Comment: @sigil - Thanks.  OK, sometimes PPT acts differently between manual user actions and programmatic ones.  Sounds like this would be one of those times.  If you set oRng to the text range you're adding, the example code I posted may get you quite close, if not on the money.

Answer (score 1):

@sigil, here's a bit of example code for starters:

```
Dim oRng As TextRange

' as a test; you'll have to parse the hyperlinks and get a refernce
' to each as a text range; this just gets a known range from
' an existing string:
Set oRng = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Characters(13, 18)

' Once you've found a range that looks like a hyperlink, this
' will assign an action setting and a hyperlink address to it:
With oRng
    .ActionSettings(1).Action = ppActionHyperlink
    .ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.Address = oRng.Text
End With
```